# Microsoft Graph returns Bad Request without details

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

I have such process:

1. Get the list of ids of SharePoint sites.
2. For each id execute such request:

```
GET, https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}?$select=id,lastModifiedDateTime,sharepointIds
```

As a result of this process, there can be two outcomes: all requests are successfully executed or some of the requests (usually 1 or 2 of 3706) return BadRequest.
Here is the sample of BadRequest:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code":"invalidRequest",
        "message":"Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "date":"2023-12-15T08:06:04",
            "request-id":"c8f40298-f38b-46de-bb27-016e929dd035",
            "client-request-id":"c8f40298-f38b-46de-bb27-016e929dd035"
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, if this process is repeated (the list of ids is the same), BadRequest will occur for different sites, and those that returned an error the previous time will successfully retrieve the correct data. So it seems that the issue is not for the particular site.

What could be the problem here?

And of course I have correct permissions and all the sites for which there was a `BadRequest` are not deleted, I also checked each one through Graph Explorer using the above-mentioned request and got the correct result.

Comment: Could it be rate-limiting?

Comment: @Dai I don't know). Typically it should return 429 in case of throttling. If you have any info that this particular error could happen because of throttling it would be great.